# Row level Trigger in Oracle: Insert statements timing issue

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

Consider the following table

```
create table testtable
(
id number(10),
batch_id number(10),
seq number(10)
)
```

An after Insert, row level trigger exists on this table which does the following:

```
create or replace trigger tr_testtable after insert on testtable
for each row

pragma autonomous_transaction

begin

v_min_seq number(10);
v_min_id number(10);
v_batch_id number(10);
v_count number(5);

select count(*) into v_count,batch_id into v_batch_id
from testtable
where batch_id = :new.batch_id
group by batch_id;

if (v_count > 1) then


with cte(min_seq,batch_id) as
(
select min(seq),batch_id from testtable
group by batch_id
)
select id into v_min_id from 
testtable tt
inner join
cte
on cte.min_seq = tt.seq
and cte.batch_id = tt.batch_id;

delete from testtable
where id <> v_min_id
and batch_id = v_batch_id;

commit;

end if;

end;
```

Following Insert statements are run:

```
insert into testtable
select 10, 100, 18 from dual;
commit;

insert into testtable
select 11, 100, 32 from dual;
commit;

insert into testtable
select 12, 100, 15 from dual;
commit;
```

So, if the above Insert statements are run, the expected output after the trigger is fired is:

```
Id  Batch_Id  Seq
12  100       15
```

Now, these Insert statements are fired at the same time.
I want to know if there is a chance that all the Insert statements execute simultaneously and the trigger fires without satisfying the condition  `if (v_count > 1)`? If yes, the output will be the following, which is undesirable:

```
Id  Batch_Id  Seq

10  100       18
11  100       32
12  100       15
```

Comment: Your code will not give the output you expect because the trigger runs in an autonomous transaction and won't see the row being inserted, so it can only work on the data previously in the table.  It may also interfere with rolling back.  This smells to me like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/150299).  What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is this -  In a batch(BatchId), save the record containing minimum sequence(Seq) and delete the other records.

Comment: Is it possible to receive two records with different ID but tied minimum SEQ?  If so, what do you want to happen?  Do you want to maintain the ID for the record with the minimum SEQ?

Comment: No, there can't be duplicate Seq tied to different Id's within a Batch_Id.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manage duplicate record, Let try another way. [MERGE statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) is the way you can specify conditions to determine whether to update or insert into the target table

```
MERGE INTO testtable t1
USING ( select 10 as id, 100 as batch_id, 18 as seq from dual ) t2
ON (t1.batch_id = t2.batch_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t1.seq = t2.seq
    WHERE t1.seq > t2.seq
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (id, batch_id, seq)
     VALUES (t2.id,t2.batch_id, t2.seq);

MERGE INTO testtable t1
USING ( select 11 as id, 100 as batch_id, 32 as seq from dual ) t2
ON (t1.batch_id = t2.batch_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t1.seq = t2.seq
    WHERE t1.seq > t2.seq
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (id, batch_id, seq)
     VALUES (t2.id,t2.batch_id, t2.seq);

MERGE INTO testtable t1
USING ( select 12 as id, 100 as batch_id, 15 as seq from dual ) t2
ON (t1.batch_id = t2.batch_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t1.seq = t2.seq
    WHERE t1.seq > t2.seq
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (id, batch_id, seq)
     VALUES (t2.id,t2.batch_id, t2.seq);
```

Comment: This solution produces a different value for ID from the one the OP posts.  That may or may not matter, depending on the specific business rule the OP wants to implement.